# Extract date from date time - change . to , and print sum up of different field

Tags: awk

```
aNumber bNumber startDate   cost    balanceAfter    trafficCase Operator    unknown3    MainAmount  BALANCEBEFORE
22676239633 433 2014-07-02 10:16:48.000 0,00    0.20    0   Short Code  397224944   0.0000  0.2000
22677277255 76919167    2014-07-02 10:16:51.000 1,00    92.60   0   Airtel  126268625   0.0000  92.6000
22676777508 76701575    2014-07-02 10:16:55.000 1,00    217.00  0   Airtel  4132186103  0.0000  217.0000
22665706841 433 2014-07-02 10:16:57.000 0,00    69.50   0   Short Code  4133821554  0.0000  69.5000
22665799922 70110055    2014-07-03 10:16:45.000 20,00   0.50    0   Telmob  126260244   20.0000 0.5000
22676239633 433 2014-07-03 10:16:48.000 0,00    0.20    0   Short Code  397224944   0.0000  0.2000
22677277255 76919167    2014-07-04 10:16:51.000 1,00    92.60   0   Airtel  126268625   0.0000  92.6000
22676777508 76701575    2014-07-04 10:16:55.000 1,00    217.00  0   Airtel  4132186103  0.0000  217.0000
22665706841 433 2014-07-05 10:16:57.000 0,00    69.50   0   Short Code  4133821554  0.0000  69.5000
```

Here is a sample of the data I have. I want to sum up `cost`, `balanceAfter`, `MainAmount` and `BALANCEBEFORE` at each time the date changed but my concern is I have date combined with time and my decimal separator is dot instead of comma so my awk script can't perform the operation.
Can I have an AWK script which will first extract only the date so in the end I will have an output looking like:

```
Date        Cost    balanceAfter    MainAmount  BALANCEBEFORE
02/07/2014  2,00    379,3                0          379,3
03/07/2014  20,00   0,7                 20            0,7
04/07/2014  2,00    309,6                0          309,6
05/07/2014  0,00    69,5                 0           69,5
```

HERE IS MY AWK SCRIPT

```
awk -F 'NR==1 {header=$0; next} {a[$3]+=$4 a[$3]+=$5 a[$3]+=$9 a[$3]+=$10} END {for (i in a) {printf "%d\t%d\n", i, a[i]}; tot+=a[i]};' out.txt>output.doc
```

Comment: According to your input someting like `sed 's/,/\./g' | awk [your actual script] > output.txt` should do the trick, if you wan't commas instead of dots in the numeric values you may pipe again to sed with the reverse regex.

Comment: Note that awk sees your date and time as two separate fields, which makes your cost $5 (instead of $4), balanceAfter $6 (instead of $5), etc.

Comment: Another issue is the Operator column --- a value like `Short Code` is two fields whereas `Airtel` is one. If OTOH your file is tab-separated things become much easier.

Comment: Even though i'm considering what you said it stills return 0 as value for sum of cost -@jas

Comment: "Short code" and "Airtel" appeared to be only in a single area @jas

Comment: if you run `awk 'NR > 1 { print "Line" NR ": " NF }' data.txt` on your data you'll see that some lines (the ones with `Short Code`) have 12 fields and the others have 11.

Comment: You right! But considering cost which is before Operator i still can't sum up based on the date change -@jas

Comment: See my answer and see if it helps. It's verbose but should be easy to compare with what you are trying. Ask any questions if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Avoid pre-processing step as per Etan Reisner's suggestion to use `$NF` to work around differing numbers of tokens in `Operator` column.

```
$ cat data.txt
aNumber bNumber startDate   cost    balanceAfter    trafficCase Operator    unknown3    MainAmount  BALANCEBEFORE
22676239633 433 2014-07-02 10:16:48.000 0,00    0.20    0   Short Code  397224944   0.0000  0.2000
22677277255 76919167    2014-07-02 10:16:51.000 1,00    92.60   0   Airtel  126268625   0.0000  92.6000
22676777508 76701575    2014-07-02 10:16:55.000 1,00    217.00  0   Airtel  4132186103  0.0000  217.0000
22665706841 433 2014-07-02 10:16:57.000 0,00    69.50   0   Short Code  4133821554  0.0000  69.5000
22665799922 70110055    2014-07-03 10:16:45.000 20,00   0.50    0   Telmob  126260244   20.0000 0.5000
22676239633 433 2014-07-03 10:16:48.000 0,00    0.20    0   Short Code  397224944   0.0000  0.2000
22677277255 76919167    2014-07-04 10:16:51.000 1,00    92.60   0   Airtel  126268625   0.0000  92.6000
22676777508 76701575    2014-07-04 10:16:55.000 1,00    217.00  0   Airtel  4132186103  0.0000  217.0000
22665706841 433 2014-07-05 10:16:57.000 0,00    69.50   0   Short Code  4133821554  0.0000  69.5000


$ cat so2.awk
NR > 1 {
    cost = $5;
    balanceAfter = $6;
    mainAmount = $(NF - 1);
    balanceBefore = $NF;

    sub(",", ".", cost);
    sub(",", ".", balanceAfter);
    sub(",", ".", mainAmount);
    sub(",", ".", balanceBefore);

    dateCost[$3] += cost;
    dateBalanceAfter[$3] += balanceAfter;
    dateMainAmount[$3] += mainAmount;
    dateBalanceBefore[$3] += balanceBefore;
}

END {
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", "Date", "Cost", "BalanceAfter", "MainAmount", "BalanceBefore");
    for (i in dateCost) {
        printf("%s\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", i, dateCost[i], dateBalanceAfter[i], dateMainAmount[i], dateBalanceBefore[i]);
    }
}


$ awk -f so2.awk data.txt
Date    Cost    BalanceAfter    MainAmount  BalanceBefore
2014-07-02  2.000000    379.300000  0.000000    379.300000
2014-07-03  20.000000   0.700000    20.000000   0.700000
2014-07-04  2.000000    309.600000  0.000000    309.600000
2014-07-05  0.000000    69.500000   0.000000    69.500000
```

Comment: You can do that fixing up in awk directly (and then force awk to re-split with `$0=$0`) but you also don't need to since you can just use `mainAmount = $(NF-1); balanceBefore = $NF;` in the script. (Also `cost` is column `$5` and `balanceAfter` is column `$6` and that output does not look to have come from that script `%s` wouldn't pad with zeros like that as far as I know.)

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner, I fixed the code to match what I actually ran in the end. Excellent point about using $NF and $(NF - 1) to work around the data issue! My printf does have that formatting default for %f for some reason. `awk 'BEGIN { printf("%f\n", 3.14) }'` gives me `3.140000`

Comment: Yes, `%f` does that. `%s` does not. `%f` is for floating point numbers.

Comment: thanks @jas. The code is correct but i have like million of lines so is there a way to combine all the tasks in one code ?

Comment: Yes, @Baodbao, see updated answer that incorporates Etan Reisner's suggestion above for avoiding the extra step.

Answer (score 0):

This requires no pre-processing of the file:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {print "Date Cost BalanceAfter MainAmount BalanceBefore"}
    NR == 1 {next} 
    function showday() {
        printf "%s\t%.2f\t%.1f\t%d\t%.1f\n", date, cost, bAfter, main, bBefore
    }
    date != $3 {
        if (date) showday()
        date = $3
        cost = bAfter = main = bBefore = 0
    } 
    {
        sub(/,/, ".", $5)
        cost += $5
        bAfter += $6
        main += $(NF-1)
        bBefore += $NF
    }
    END {showday()}
' file | column -t
```

```
Date        Cost   BalanceAfter  MainAmount  BalanceBefore
2014-07-02  2.00   379.3         0           379.3
2014-07-03  20.00  0.7           20          0.7
2014-07-04  2.00   309.6         0           309.6
2014-07-05  0.00   69.5          0           69.5
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn! It works fine but there is a issue. Your script stipulates the input have to be well "classified". What i mean is by having 2014-07-02 before and after 2014-07-03 the script will return me as output       * 2014-07-02 *2014-07-03 *2014-07-02 instead of unique 2014-07-02 and 2014-07-03

Comment: That is true. If your data is really like that, use jas's answer instead: it will be correct.